# Displaying Day and Date from feed

Tags: javascript, python, django

How do I display the following as a a Day, Month?

"2013-05-28T00:00:00.0000000" as Tuesday, May 28 ?

thanks.

Comment: is this javascript or python?

Comment: This question is very low quality, there is no detail. To display the Day and month, you need to hide the year, timezone, hour, minute, seconds and milliseconds

Comment: I'd like to do it in either language, the feed is a JSON API

Comment: For a real answer we need more

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info.  So essentially I've managed to grab all the data I need from the feed but would like to conver the above into a suitable format to display on the page.

The data is inside the node: "QuoteDate": "2013-05-28T00:00:00.0000000"

Just not sure how I would do this...

Answer (score 2):

So since you have tagged the question as both `javascript` and `python`

I will recommend two libraries that solve the issue.

Using http://momentjs.com/ you can solve your problem as follows [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)

Using http://delorean.readthedocs.org you can solve your problem as follows [here](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#strings-and-parsing)

Answer (score 2):

If in python you can do it like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime('2013-05-28T00:00:00.0000000','%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.0000000').strftime('%A %b, %d')
>>>'Tuesday May, 28'
```

This will output in your current `locale` language.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this is javascript it will look something like the following

```
var d = new Date();
d.toISOString();
document.write(d);
```